# Turbo Pascal 3.01A turboh error: "co processor card not responding"

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, turbo-pascal

I'm using a very old version of Turbo Pascal and it uses the **turboh.com** to compile.

What is special about this *.com (as far as I can tell) is that it will compile on a very old computer we have but we are unable to emulate it correctly.

We have tried **DOSBOX** and **Virtual PC 2007*** with Windows 95. The Virtual PC 2007 with W95 is as close as we can get to the OS of the old computer that compiles.

The only error that we receive is:

```
"CO PROCESSOR CARD NOT RESPONDING".
```

I've tried to google for this error and resolution to no success.

As far as how I'm trying to compile with Turbo Pascal, we're using a version that allows you to compile to a .com and control the starting and ending memory address. I've tried different versions of Turbo Pascal and none of them seem to have that option. If I use a newer version it has a syntax error.

I'm not hugely experienced in Turbo Pascal so rewriting the program isn't an option at this time. Mainly, we're just trying to find legacy emulation support that will prevent this error. The old computer in question is an **i486**.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Either did not copy configuration properly (some other small files with TP config settings, *.dsk, *.cfg maybe?), or some benchmarking code overflows. Simply set your emulation to slower.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you need to turn off a switch in the IDE to avoid generating specific asm instructions for the numeric coprocessor that was optional on older PCs e.g. 80387. Take a look in the menus and you should be able to turn it off. I don't remember exactly where since it has been a while since I touched a turbo pascal compiler (like 2 decades).

Comment: Ok. Do you know if this is contained within the turboh.com or is it somewhere else? The turboh.com won't run at all and regular turbo.com gives me a completely different set of options and won't compile. I'm not very familiar with .com files, is it possible a turboh.com -? command that would let me change it?